# What is the GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri class, and is its absence in Windows the death knell to CiviCRM under IIS?

Tags: mailing, core

I switched a development environment running under Joomla and IIS to the CiviCRM:master branch.  It now fails with

0 Class 'GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri' not found

Is this a Linux-specific class?  If not, where do you find it?  CiviCRM 4.7.x did not need it.

Answer (score 1):

.

1. cd to PHP install directory.
2. composer require GuzzleHttp/psr7
3. Add this to CiviCRM.settings.php: require_once $_SERVER["PHPRC"]. '/vendor/autoload.php';

Answer (score 1):

@stehpen what you could also do there is cd to the civicrm dir and run `composer install` That will ensure that everything the .lock file requires is installed and it will also update the composer autoloader for civicrm.

Answer (score 0):

1. Guzzle is a client library for making HTTP requests. As with many PHP libraries required by Civi, it's declared in `composer.json`.
2. When setting up an installation via `git`, one's process must install all current dependencies. Whenever I change to a different version, I usually do this with `./bin/setup.sh -D` (or something even higher level, like `./bin/setup.sh` or `civibuild reinstall`), but I don't know if those work under Joomla. The main things to look out for:

   - Install PHP dependencies with composer (i.e. `composer install`)
   - Install JS/CSS dependencies with bower (i.e. `bower install`)
3. If you want to install the `master` branch on Joomla -- without digging into the build system -- consider grabbing an autobuild file from https://download.civicrm.org/latest